# Keycloak - multiple Google clients for scope elevation

Tags: google-oauth, keycloak

Can I have two Google external identity providers (with two clients set up in Google) and choose the one to use dynamically? Allow me to explain my use case.

My service requires users to have a Google account, thus I plan for the initial log in to Keycloack to occur via Google IDP 1 with *basic* scopes.

My service *optionally* uses the Google Sheets API. I want to give my users the choice of enabling that feature or not. If the user does want to leverage the added functionality, I would revoke the first Google consent, then direct the user to login via Google IDP 2 with the Google Sheets API scope, saving the Google refresh token for subsequent server to server work against the Sheets API.

Does this make any sense? Is there a better way? Why won't Keycloak allow me to add two Google IDPs? I guess it's easy enough to create a second instance manually.

Thanks!

Comment: A better approach is to use a single client on Google and ask for the scopes as needed. The problem is that it does not seem possible to get Keycloak to alter the Default Scopes set up in the IdP in a dynamic manner. Using two IdPs could work but then the user is asked to merge their accounts unecessarily.

I believe I'll need to keep Keycloak out of the picture and just authenticate straight to Google.